# How much experience is needed when I multiclass into a new class?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, experience-points, character-levels

How much experience is needed to take my first level in a new class in D&D 5e? I'm interested in going from 4th level Sorcerer to 1st level Cleric. Is the experience point cost the same as normal levelling?

Answer (score 21):

### The level of the class doesn't matter to experience required when levelling.

Character level is separate from class level in 5e. Which means your character is becoming level 5.

The experience required to go from level 4 to level 5 is 3,800 experience.

This answer can be found in the **PHB pg. 15; Character Avancement table**.

Multi-classing rules can be found in the **PHB pg.163**.

Comment: So let me get this right. In order to get lvl 1 claric, i need 3'800 exp (as a lvl 4)

Comment: That is correct. It's because you aren't levelling the class, you're levelling the character. Taking the class on your level up as a multi-class is part of your character's progression.

Comment: @Maximonious It may be easier to say "in order to reach [character] level 5, you need 3,800 XP.  When you reach level 5, you can gain a level in the Sorcerer class, or gain a level in the Cleric class instead."

Comment: @Maximonious It's worth seconding that you should look at the multi-classing rules. When you reach level 5, in addition to your cleric level, you'll gain an increase in your overall spell slots (you will have 3rd level spell slots, but not spells), damage increase for cantrips, and an increase in your proficiency bonus which will apply to the save DCs for both cleric and sorcerer. The multiclass boons are significantly different from 3.5 so don't let prior experience mislead you.